# TIdTCPClient ignores ReadTimeout

Tags: delphi, tcpclient, indy

I use `TIdTCPClient` to send a message and receive an answer. My messages and answers are fairly well-structured, in this meaning that they can have different length, but always ends with a `#FS` character.

My Delphi (Alexandria) code is like the following:

```pascal
_TcpClient := TIdTCPClient.Create(Self);
_TcpClient.ReadTimeout := 60000;
_TcpClient.ConnectTimeout := 30000;
_TcpClient.Host := X.X.X.X;
_TcpClient.Port := Y;
```

Then I send my message:

```pascal
_TcpClient.Connect;
_TcpClient.IOHandler.Write(messageText);
```

And finally, I wait for the other party to confirm the message with ACK (that, as I said, ends with `#FS`):

```pascal
try
  ans := TStringStream.Create;
  repeat
    b := _TcpClient.IOHandler.ReadByte;
    ans.Write(b,1);
  until b = #FS;
  b := _TcpClient.IOHandler.ReadByte;
  ans.Write(b, 1);
except
  _status := ssAckTimeout;
end;
```

All this works fairly well for short messages, but with larger ones (~100k) over the internet, it fails.

The last block of code falls into the `except` section after 8-10 seconds without reading anything.

My understanding of how the component works is that it should read byte by byte, waiting either for `ReadTimeout` or `#FS`. I have no idea why it ignores my `ReadTimeout` value and fails after as little as 8 seconds.

Does anyone know the answer, or could propose the solution?

Answer (score 0):

The `IOHandler.ReadByte()` method *does* honor the `ReadTimeout` property, despite your claim that it does not.  The only way it could raise an error earlier than expected is if there is a flaw in the OS's socket stack.

However, there is a *potential* flaw in your code. Your loop reads until `#FS` arrives and is written into `ans`, and then it tries to read *one more byte* past `#FS`.  Unless your messages actually have such a trail byte (a checksum, perhaps?), then this will fail and corrupt your communications.

In any case, rather then calling `ReadByte()` in a loop, a *much* simpler solution is to use the `IOHandler.ReadLn()` method instead, specifying `#FS` as the delimiter to end the line, eg:

```
var
  ans: string;
...
ans := _TcpClient.IOHandler.ReadLn(#FS);
```

Comment: Hi Remy... thank you for the prompt answer - really appreciate! In fact my message does contain one more character after the #FS. It is #CR, which is not really important ... nevertheless, I changed my code as you proposed and noticed that the code falls into error after 8 sec with 'connection closed gracefully' message. TIdTcpClient is said that it throws such error 'always' when it faces timeout, so it is not any real indication of the error's reason, but maybe it is? Maybe this is true reason of my problem? Could you please put more light on it?

Comment: "*my message does contain one more character after the #FS. It is #CR*" - then, you can use `ReadLn(#FS#CR)`. "*the code falls into error ... 'connection closed gracefully'*" - that means the server is actively closing the TCP connection on its end while you are still reading bytes. Maybe the server goofed, or maybe you are simply reading too many bytes than the server actually sends. "*TIdTcpClient is said that it throws such error 'always' when it faces timeout*" - that is not true at all. If a real timeout happens, it raises an `EIdReadTimeout('Read timed out.')` exception instead.